# Implementing a Build Heap function by Insertion

Tags: java, algorithm, heap, implementation

can you please tell me whether these two pseudo codes for building a heap will always return the SAME HEAP?
This is the "classic" well known BuildHeap code:

**BuildHeap(A)**  // A is an unsorted array

```
for(i = A.size/2 down to 1) do 
    MaxHeapify(A,i)
```

This is the building of a heap with insertion code:

**Build-Max-Heap-By-Insertion(A)**

```
heapsize[A] = 1
for i=2 to length[A]
    Max-Heap-Insert(A,A[i])
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you are doing and what your term mean in more detail.  Can you provide a reference to this "well known BuildHeap code"?

Comment: @PeterLawrey:
http://homepages.ius.edu/rwisman/C455/html/notes/Chapter6/BldHeap.htm

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are referring to the linear time way to build a heap from scratch, and comparing it with building a heap iteratively, accepting one item at a time, with the heap invariant true after every insertion. Both of these - assuming that you get all the details right - will finish by building something that is a heap.

In the first case, note that if the array already satisfies the heap invariant, it will not be changed. This means that any way of arranging the objects which amounts to a valid heap will not be changed. Since there may be more than one such arrangements - especially if there are keys that compare equally - there can be no guarantee that the particular arrangement that you end up with will match any other way of creating a valid heap from the same items.